# spring boot connection to localhost database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring-boot

Is it possible to connect a database from mamp server(localhost) using a spring boot app in eclipse and display data from it? Or how does it work, because I have no idea how to implement that?

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbtuts
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=root
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

this is what, I've been using for application.properties

Comment: That would be a MySQL database. I don't know Spring Boot specifically but it's fairly easy with the JDBC and the MySQL JDBC drivers. There are some references to MySQL here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: thanks, but I tried that. it always appears to be something wrong when I enter the URL to the database and it fails to run

Comment: can you please share settings that you are using to connect?

Comment: i added the code I've been using. I tried the one that is shown below, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Following settings seem to work fine for me.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using WAMP server 3.0.6
Default port for MySql is 3306 so the following works for me

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBname
spring.datasource.username=dbusername
spring.datasource.password=dbpassword
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of anyone using MySQL from MAMP. Following Configuration worked for me.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/join_test?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```